# Format Datatable once all the data has been loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

I am trying out [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html). That is the example I am looking at, when I try it when I refresh the page I get ALL the items showing, not just the first 10 and pagination.
However when I do a filter/search, then the table works i.e its re-formatted showing 10 items and pagination. I have placed the following script to "force" the limit of 10 items and pagination but it doesn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').dataTable( {
      "paging": true,
      "pageLength": 10,
      "lengthMenu": [10,15],
      "displayLength": 10
    } )


});
</script>
```

It seems that the script is not executed until I try to filter the table or change the items displayed. The default behaviour seems to be show everything.

How can I change it so the default behaviour is show 10 items and set the pagination up. I'm using firefox and chrome, as well as the latest bootstrap

> ***************Found it*************

Sorry the error was that I was using an older version of jquery, at least that what it seems

I've changed

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and simplified the script to

```
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],

    } );
} );
        </script>
```

And it's worked fine

Comment: I think that your configuration at `lengthMenu` should be two dimensional array like this [example ](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html)

Comment: I tried that and it made no difference.

Comment: What version of datatables? You've initialised with a lower case `d` which suggests v1.9...

Comment: maybe `"displayLength": 10` is the error, delete this option. What you want with this option? I do not see in the datatables docs.